# Problema consumiendo una API desde REACT

Tags: api, reactjs, wordpress-plugin

buen día

Estoy teniendo un pequeño problema y necesito ayuda

Tengo mi backend creado utilizando wordpress con el plugin wp api rest, y este me devuelve varias secciones, posts, pages, etc.

Cuando voy a mi pagina principal consumo todos los blogs así

```
    componentDidMount() {
    return fetch(`http://localhost/wordpress/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          posts: responseJson,
        });
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        console.log(this.state.posts)

      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log('Error Response Data', error.response.data);
          console.log('Error Response Status', error.response.status);
          console.log('Error Response Headers', error.response.headers);
        } else if (error.request) {
          console.log('Error Request', error.request);
        } else {
          console.log('Error Message', error.message);
        }
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        console.log('Error Config', error.config);
      })
  }
```

Y en el front como son varios datos me permite mapear para poder ir creando cada uno en el front con esto

```
{this.state.pages.map((item, index) => {
              <div key={index}>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="leftcolumn">
                      <div className="card">
                        <div className="title">
                          <h1>{item.title.rendered}</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.content.rendered }} />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            })}
```

Y como puede verse en la consola devuelve que es un arreglo

[image: imagen consola]

Pero en la parte de las paginas, o las entradas del blog en cada uno de los links que intento consumir con esto

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    return fetch(`http://localhost/wordpress/?rest_route=/wp/v2/pages/${id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          pages: responseJson,
        });
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        console.log(this.state.pages)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log('Error Response Data', error.response.data);
          console.log('Error Response Status', error.response.status);
          console.log('Error Response Headers', error.response.headers);
        } else if (error.request) {
          console.log('Error Request', error.request);
        } else {
          console.log('Error Message', error.message);
        }
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        console.log('Error Config', error.config);
      })
  }
```

Me marca error al intentar mapear los datos, y si me voy a la consola para ver que es lo que devuelve esa ejecución me devuelve lo siguiente

[image: objeto]

donde ya directamente me devuelve el objeto y no encuentro como iterar el elemento para poder obtener los datos

lo intenté con la función map, pero marca que no hay datos para poder hacer algo, intenté leerlo directamente con

```
{this.state.pages.title.rendered}
{this.state.pages.content.rendered}
```

y con estos me marca error también, diciendo que no tiene función rendered, pero en el archivo de wordpress es parte del nombre nada mas

[image: wordpress api]

Incluso hice

```
{this.state.pages}
```

y me daba todo lo que tenía el, devolvía id, title, content, date

```
{this.state.pages.title}
```

entonces añadí la opción title, pues es la que requería y me decia que tenia la opción rendered

```
{this.state.pages.title.rendered}
```

como vi que decía que tenía el rendered que es lo que necesito que se imprima lo añadí y en este punto me marca un error que dice 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined

Siendo que como se ve en la imagen superior, si existe

[image: error]

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el JSON que genera tu REST API?

Comment: Si claro, añado los 2 que requiero

https://pastebin.com/tA0rYfhB  <-- este es el de las paginas, el que logro consumir bien

https://pastebin.com/rPvfyDBY <-- y este el que no logro hacer que react me reconozca